# WebSocket connections deselecting in Chrome DevTools Network Viewer

Tags: google-chrome, websocket, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to use the Chrome DevTools Network viewer to inspect WebSocket frames. I'm not sure if i've discovered a bug or something i'm doing wrong. Essentially, while inspecting the frames, whenever a new frame is recevied, the Network viewer jumps away/deselects the websocket connection. It is particularly bad when there are "ping" type messages being sent every 5-10 seconds, as this makes it almost impossible to keep the frames tab open.

My Chrome version is 58.0.3029.110 (64-bit)

Steps to reproduce:

1. Hit F12 to open DevTools
2. Navigate to http://www.websocket.org/echo.html
3. Check "Use secure WebSocket (TLS)" and click Connect
4. In DevTools, goto the Network tab and find the websocket connection for the chat (wss://echo.websocket.org/?encoding=text), select it and view the Frames.
5. Click Send on the page to send a message.
6. The "?encoding=text" websocket item in the network list will deselect itself and the frames view is gone!.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a workaround which you can make use of till this bug gets fixed.

Apply search filter to get the required websocket request alone as the displayed item, now the selected blue bg will get hidden but frames tab will not get closed.

Useful filters:

- is:running will show currently active websocket request.
- domain:requireddomain.com will filter required domain

[image: Defocus workaround]

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this is a bug, as others have reported the same issue [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=720356&q=devtools%20websocket&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified).